# Finding Dense rank in mysql involving multiple attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, rank, dense-rank

**How to find the dense rank based on multiple attributes?**

Product table has 2 columns *LastReceiptCost* and *ProductId*.

There can be 2 rows with similar ProductID's but different rates.

I am able to find the rank only based on the LastReceiptCost.Following is the sql scipt for that..

```
SELECT ProductID,
IF(@score=s.LastReceiptCost, @rank:=@rank, @rank:=@rank+1) rank,
@score:=s.LastReceiptCost Lcost
FROM ProductVendor s,
(SELECT @score:=0, @rank:=0) r
ORDER BY LastReceiptCost DESC,ProductID ;
```

following image shows the o/p i am getting: [Rank output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaSMz.png)

how to find the rank based on sorting both the product id and LastReceiptcost
like the following:

```
ProductId    Lcost        Rank
AA         1450        1
AA         1350        2
AA         1300        3
BB         345         1
BB         345         1
BB         300         2
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query